# What is the best way to calling the element of object repository

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I' am new to Selenium-java and I need to know what is the best way to call elements when automating the web application. please find the below way

the method, I tried (my way)

**Class File**

[image]

**property file**

[image]

kindly let me know what are the best ways with an example , thanks

Comment: Are you facing any error? Which line?

Comment: nope, perfectly working, but I need to know the proper way from you guys,

Comment: this would be a long answer. in short, you can use standard practice with design pattern as POM design pattern with singleton. Generally OR with help of properties file is not part of POM as it would be complex to maintain when Test cases will be more in number. In POM, you can manage locators on pages and common locators will be in BasePage object and its easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use POM Concept which widely used in selenium to maintain locators. This will be very helpful to reduce your code readability. You can refer below example in your case,

```
By uname = By.xpath("//input[@name='username']");
```

To use above locator ,

```
driver.findelement(uname).sendkeys("abc");
```

You can explore many more for POM Concept.